# Generating Random Numbers Securely in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, security, random

Where can I find an industry-accepted secure pseudo-random number generator for Objective-C? Is there one built in to the OS X SDK?

My question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160890/generating-random-numbers-in-objective-c), except that I'm looking for a **secure** PRNG.

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for the help. Here's a simple one-liner to implement the /dev/random method:

```
-(NSData *)getRandomBytes:(NSUInteger)length {
    return [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"/dev/random"] readDataOfLength:length];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Security.framework has a facility for doing this, called [SecRandomCopyBytes()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html). Although it's really basically just copying from `/dev/random`.

Comment: Is SecRandomCopyBytes [supported in OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510638/encrypt-nsstring-using-aes-128-and-a-key)?

Comment: Ah looks like SecRandomCopyBytes was [added in Lion](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/MacOSXLionAPIDiffs/Security.html). I'd like to support 10.6.. any alternatives?

Comment: Hmm.. is [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg00620.html) a problem?

Comment: @pepsi: Not unless you're working for the NSA. It's Good Enough™ for everyone else to use. The `/dev/random` entropy pool is fed by a root-level daemon that collects timing information from the kernel, so unless you're running on a horribly broken system where that daemon isn't running, you should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
int SecRandomCopyBytes (
   SecRandomRef rnd,
   size_t count,
   uint8_t *bytes
);.
```

This [function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Reference/RandomizationReference/Reference/reference.html) is available in Security/Security.h  Framework. 
This function reads from /dev/random to obtain an array of cryptographically-secure random bytes.

> /dev/random is a blocking interface that only returns as much random
>   data as the system possesses at any particular time. Once the system
>   runs out of randomness, no more can be fetched until more is generated
>   (by listening to the user bang on the keyboard, or however the OS
>   gathers true randomness). /dev/urandom is a non-blocking interface
>   that always returns the requested amount of data, by using a
>   pseudorandom generator even when true randomness is exhausted.**OS X has both of these as well, however they both act like /dev/urandom does on Linux.**

[Random Numbers](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-03-18-random-numbers.html) 
[random(4) Mac OS X Manual Page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man4/random.4.html)
[How good is SecRandomCopyBytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832941/how-good-is-secrandomcopybytes)