# Unable to generate an AES 256 key from password and salt for use with RNCryptor

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, salt, rncryptor

I want to generate a key with Salt for AES 256 encryption.I am using BBASE lib, referred this link:
[Create random 128 bit AES Encryption key in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531515/create-random-128-bit-aes-encryption-key-in-ios)

My code is:

```
    NSData* salt = [BBAES randomDataWithLength:BBAESSaltDefaultLength];
            NSData *key = [BBAES keyBySaltingPassword:@"password" salt:salt         keySize:BBAESKeySize256 numberOfIterations:BBAESPBKDF2DefaultIterationsCount];
            NSLog(@"Data ASE Key %@",key);
            NSString *aString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:key encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I want to use this 'key' into the following code:(here I am using RNCryptor lib)

```
    NSData *encryptedData = [ RNEncryptor encryptData:bodyData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:aString error:&error];

    NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:encryptedData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:aString error:&error];
```

I need to pass key of type NSString,But when I am converting NSData to NSString it gives NULL value and my application crashes. What should I do?? Is there any solution for this ??

Comment: RNCryptor will perform the key derivation for you, using a random salt. Is there any reason you want to do this derivation yourself?

Answer (score 2):

Not all data is a valid UTF-8 string, most random data is not. Basically that is why Base64 exists, to convert 8-bit data to an ASCII string--and back. There are of course other methods.

But as Duncan states, why? Read the RNCryptor code, it already handles converting a password (string) to a secure key.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you @Duncan & @Zaph :) I found a solution!!

Instead of

```
    NSString *aString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:key encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I used this:

```
    NSString *aString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:key encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: You really need to study encodings and understand what is going on.