# Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES"); in Objective C

Tags: java, android, objective-c, aes

I have this code in Java:

```
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
```

I want to port this code to objective-c?

Comment: I don't understand mutch about objective c but I found this code that generates an AES key give it a try http://stackoverflow.com/a/23534490/5467727

Comment: If the given answer solved your problem, you may [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) it. If it didn't, then please expand on what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`Key` and `SecretKeySpec` are simple container types for Java's [jce](/questions/tagged/jce). They don't have corresponding types in Objective-C (CommonCrypto). `keyValue` is a simple `byte[]` that corresponds to a byte array in Objective-C which you can use there.