# how to generate a secured random number using sha1PRNG algorithm in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sha1

I want to generate a random number using sha1PRNG using objective c.I tried searching for this but didn't get any information regarding this.Can you please provide me some information regarding this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be relevant: [Generating random numbers securely in objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234686/generating-random-numbers-securely-in-objective-c)

Comment: Using SHA1PRNG to generate random numbers on server side.So we have to generate random number using SHA1PRNG.

Comment: If the numbers generated are to be truly random, why does the same algorithm matter?

Comment: No.Not getting the response from server.